# Decomposing an Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, my goal is to decompose the graph into sub-graphs such that the resulted graph is a graph with no cycle in a way that the following quantity is minimized $$m_1!\times m_2! \times ... \times m_M! \times M!$$ where $m_i$ denotes the number of nodes in subgraph $i$, and $M$ denotes the number of nodes in the resulted graph. Attached you can find a simple example. Each node in the resulted graph composed of one or more nodes from the original graph. I was wondering if anyone can suggest an algorithm to do such decomposition. For instance in this example, we have $2! \times 2! \times 1! \times 4! \times 4!$
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crIZW.jpg)

Comment: that made no sense to me.

Comment: Indeed:  very confusing.

Comment: The core idea is to replace each subset of vertexes that contains loops by a single vertex (which of course doesn't contain a loop)—as shown by the hand-drawn contours in the example figure.  Note, though, that his/her "solution" does not optimize the number of final vertexes.  (I *think* the poser is just confused here.)

Comment: Thank you for your note. My apology for phrasing this question poorly. David rephrased my question very well. I just need to add the the resulted graph is not DAG, but a graph which does not have any cycle. In addition, my example does not give a graph with maximum number of nodes. Having said that, I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Your example does not give the maximum number of "meta" nodes.  I urge you to take your time to ask your question carefully and craft a *correct* illustrative example, otherwise people who might help you will not.

Comment: A polynomial time algorithm I suppose?

Comment: The example you propose does not seem to be optimal. Eg. if you consider a "bag" containing two vertices it can be further split into two bags each containing a single vertex, no?

Comment: A polynomial time algorithm is preferable, but it is okay even if it is not polynomial.

Comment: If the polynomial time constraint is dropped, then simply iterate over all partitions of the vertex set, compute the underlying graph and just keep the ones that result in acyclic graphs. Out of all the acyclic graphs return the one(s) with the maximum number of vertices (or the one that minimizes the product you specified in the updated question).

Comment: Seems like an interesting question. Any motivation behind it?

Comment: I'm using it in graphical models.

Comment: @ fidbc thanks for your solution. Although the algorithm needs to be linear, what you proposed is probably prohibitive computationally. I have a graph with over 1,000,000 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I *think* the poser requests:

Here is a general undirected graph (isomorphic to the one in his/her example):

[image]

Now, identify subgraphs that contain loops:

[image]

Now replace the marked subgraphs by single vertexes.

Comment: This does not seem to maximize the number of nodes as was originally asked, since, say vertices 14,15,16 and 17 could be put in 3 different sets, say $\{14\}, \{15,17\}$ and $\{16\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, given your constructive comment, my problem, after replacing the marked subgraphs by single vertexes, boils down to decomposing a tree into several subgraphs such that the defined quantity i.e., $m_1 \times m_2 \times ... m_M \times M!$ is minimized.